# ASP.NET Core website not running in docker even though container appears to be running

Tags: windows, docker, asp.net-core, docker-desktop

This is my first docker try. I am using Windows 10, installed Docker Desktop and using Windows containers. I have created a simple hello world type asp.net core web application in VS Code and trying to run it in docker.

I wrote code in VS Code then published it in folder `/bin/Publish`. Then inside `Publish` folder I created `Dockerfile` as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019  
COPY . /inetpub/wwwroot
```

After that image was downloaded which can be seen in below screenshot. First image `naziacore` is the one I am trying to run.

[image]

Then I ran docker using following command:

```
docker run -i -d -p 80:80 naziacore
```

But when I open browser and type `http://localhost` then website doesn't open. It shows that standard error like website is down or you don't have internet connection.

Running following command shows that container is running.

[image]

I can see that files have been copied to `inetpub/wwwroot`

[image]

I even tried a different port but no luck. How to diagnose and fix this issue?

Comment: It is better to let visual studio create the dockerfile for you. There is an option to add docker support to your app in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing some parts of your dockerfile. I'd recommend you check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows&pivots=dotnet-8-0), but I think adding an entrypoint to the end is what you probably need:

```
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "NaziaDocker.dll"]
```